# Why can't I set the present working directory by setting PWD

Tags: c, linux, process

I want to set the current working directory for a child program. I am setting it with `setenv("PWD", "/media", 1);` in the parent and starting the child with `system(...);`. But when the child calls `getcwd(0, 0)` it is returning /root.

I thought child processes were supposed to inherit the environment from their parent?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html

Comment: Thanks very much.  chdir() seems to work.  But then that leads me to another question - why doesn't setenv() work?  I have a list of env variables that need to be set for this child and it's a pity I have to use a different library function for this one variable.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX compliant shells set the `PWD` environment variable to the current working directory. However, the actual current working directory is a property of the process itself (inherited by children spawned using `system` or `fork`) and needs to be changed with [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html).

Changes to the `PWD` environment variable variable don't change anything, and the variable does not necessarily actually reflect the current working directory (if it was changed by something other than the shell).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.